# Error codificación ISO-8859-1

Tags: html, utf-8

Estoy haciendo una prueba sencilla con el siguiente código HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <label> Esto es una prueba con la ñ y los acentos ò </label>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me arroja lo siguiente, lo cual está mal, el problema se soluciona cambiando el charset a UTF-8, sin embargo, la documentación de ISO-8859-1 dice que sirve para el alfabeto latino incluyendo las ñ y los acentos, alguien sabe la razón por la que esto no funciona?

Comment: Para que la computadora entienda esos dígitos debes poner el UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione debes guardar el archivo con dicha codificación, si estás usando sublimetext, ve a: `File > Save whith encoding > Western(ISO 8859-1)`.

En otros editores debe existit la forma de hacerlo parecida. Aunque yo recomiendo usar `charset="UTF-8"` ya que es mas extenso.

Answer (score 1):

La códificación para **UTF-8** e **ISO-8859-1** son diferentes. A lo mejor lo que quiere decir documentación de la ISO-8859-1 es que es compatible con ASCII, pero no con UTF-8.

Primero asegúrate de que el editor que usas está guardando los archivos html con la codificación UTF-8 y en la página HTML tendrás que cambiar a:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

También puedes usar ISO-8859-1 si lo prefieres asegurándote de seguir los mismos pasos para esta codificación, aunque es recomendable usar UTF-8